# Programmatically add and remove woocommerce product category

Tags: php

I have an existing product category in woocommerce called 'whats-new', with an ID of 35.
I want to progmatically add all (existing and new) products less than 30 days old to that category, without going through and ticking them all.

Then any products that go over the 30 days, automatically remove that category.

I feel like there must be a way to do this in WordPress, but it's proving pretty difficult for some reason and I'm going round in circles a little.

I have the following code, which is basically what I want to achieve. The time function works, but adding and remove thing category does not:

```
    $product = wc_get_product($id);

    global $product;

    $datetime_created  = $product->get_date_created(); 
    $timestamp_created = $datetime_created->getTimestamp();
    $datetime_now      = new WC_DateTime();
    $timestamp_now     = $datetime_now->getTimestamp();
    $time_delta        = $timestamp_now - $timestamp_created;
    $sixty_days        = 60 * 24 * 60 * 60;

    $cat_ids = array( 35 );

    if ( $time_delta < $sixty_days ) {
        // NEW PRODUCT - add 'whats-new' category
        wp_set_object_terms( $product_id, $cat_ids, 'product_cat', true );
    } elseif ( $time_delta > $sixty_days ) {
        // OLD PRODUCT - remove 'whats-new' category
        wp_remove_object_terms( $product_id, $cat_ids, 'product_cat', true );
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the codes below to a custom plugin

To add the category to new products

```
function set_new_product_cat( $post_id, $post, $update ) {
    if("product" === $post->post_type){
        // Exit out as we are updating an existing product 
        if ( $update ) {
            return;
        }
        
        //Appends the category 35 to the product
        wp_set_post_categories( $post->ID, 35, true);
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_insert_post', 'set_new_product_cat', 10, 3 );
```

and this for setting up a cron task to once a day check for products older then 30 days that have the category still set and unset it

```
function remove_new_product_cat_deactivate() {
    wp_clear_scheduled_hook( 'remove_new_product_cat_cron' );
}
 
add_action('init', function() {
    add_action( 'remove_new_product_cat_cron', 'remove_new_product_cat_run_cron' );
    register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'remove_new_product_cat_deactivate' );
 
    if (! wp_next_scheduled ( 'remove_new_product_cat_cron' )) {
        wp_schedule_event( time(), 'daily', 'remove_new_product_cat_cron' );
    }
});
function remove_new_product_cat_run_cron() {
    // Get all products older then 30 days that have the category with id 35
    $args = array(
        'numberposts'      => -1,
        'category'         => 35,
        'post_type'        => 'product',
        'date_query' => array(
            'before' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-30 days')) 
        )
    );
    $products = get_posts($args);
    
    // Loop trough the products
    foreach ( $products as $product) {
        // Grab an array of currently set categories
        $cats  = wp_get_post_categories($product);
        
        // Remove 35 from the list
        if (($key = array_search(35, $cats)) !== false) {
            unset($messages[$key]);
        }
        
        // Update the categories overwriting existing ones
        wp_set_post_categories( $post->ID, $cats, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that Jasper. Where do I add this code? I've added it to my functions.php but it doesn't seem to be doing anything. The category hasn't been applied to the new items and some of the old items still have the category. Sorry, this is a new one for me. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Update, I've added this to a custom plugin, activated it and it still doesn't work :/

Comment: @Leanne Did you manage to get it working?? I would like to use this too, but it doesn't work for me either.